# Check if file exists works in VBA sub but not in VBA function despite calling the same function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to check for existence of a file

If I run the following code by running a macro

```
Sub CheckFile()

  f = "I:\SomeFolder\a.txt"

  returnvalue = Dir(f)

  MsgBox (returnvalue)

End Sub
```

I get "a.txt" in a message box because file exists! As supposed!
But if I write a function

```
Function FileExists(f)
    
    returnvalue = Dir(f)
    
    FileExists = returnvalue

End Function
```

and use =FileExists(A1) with A1 having value of "I:\SomeFolder\a.txt"

I get 0 ?????????

Same function, same input, different result. I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I must read upon scope of the variable. Changing (f) to (g) within FileExists definition did the trick.